# Stop NetworkManager changing an interface in monitor mode to managed mode without turning it off

Tags: networking, network-manager, network-monitoring

I am working in a project which requires me to have one interface in monitor mode and 2 in managed mode.
The way I set the monitor mode in the interface is as follows:

```
sudo ifconfig {iface} down
sudo iwconfig {iface} mode monitor
sudo ifconfig {iface} up
```

This does the job but after a while the interface automatically goes to managed mode. I googled a bit and it and someone has already asked here about the issue ([Wifi interface mode switches automatically back to managed (Ubuntu 20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1330483/618353)), but [chili555's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1330535/618353) only explains how to turn off the `NetworkManager` service.

In my case I would like the `NetworManager` service to keep running. Is there a way to achieve this?
I would also like to avoid using `airmon-ng` if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've been running devices with one monitor and one managed for years, and this only started happening on one device yesterday. I'm trying to determine what is different about this device, and I've found this, https://support.qacafe.com/cdrouter/knowledge-base/prevent-network-manager-from-controlling-an-interface/

> ### Configure Network Manager to ignore test interfaces
>
> Network Manager has a command line tool that can be used to see which interfaces it is controlling. Pull up a terminal window and type the following command:
>
> ```
> nmcli dev status
> ```
>
> This displays a table that lists all network interfaces along with their `STATE`. If Network Manager is not controlling an interface, its `STATE` will be listed as `unmanaged`. Any other value indicates the interface is under Network Manager control.
>
> The preferred way to tell Network Manager to stop controlling an interface is by creating/updating a file in the `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/` directory and giving it the following content. You can name the file anything with a `.conf` suffix, but all files in that directory will be read in asciibetical order. Files read later override snippets of files read earlier. Make sure the `keyfile` plugin is listed. Other plugins may be listed too.
>
> ```
> [main] plugins=ifcfg-rh,keyfile
>
> [keyfile] unmanaged-devices=interface-name:eth0;interface-name:wifi1
> ```
>
> The keyfile section can also include wildcards and exceptions as follows:
>
> ```
> [keyfile]
> unmanaged-devices=interface-name:eth*,except:interface-name:eth0,except:interface-name:eth3;interface-name:wifi*
> ```
>
> Interfaces can also be defined by their MAC addresses (in lower case):
>
> ```
> [keyfile]
> unmanaged-devices=mac:00:11:22:33:44:55;mac:66:77:88:99:00:aa
> ```
>
> Reboot for the changes to take effect.

It has resolved my particular issue.